# kickstart file /run/install/ks.cfg is missing centos

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, centos, unix

I am in a bit of trouble in regards to an kickstart installation and this is done via net install and is running on VMWARE sphere.

All systems have as well been updated and upgraded to the latest kernel

The image is gathered via an file server. But upon running the kickstart installation. I am recieving the following error:

```
kickstart file /run/install/ks.cfg missing
```

**Kickstart**

```
15:31:39,508 ERR anaconda.stdout: Kickstart file /run/install/ks.cfg is missing
```

Checking NGINX logs serverside on the fileserver storing the kickstart configuration. There is requests recieved but, presented with an error code of 304.

Down below NGINX logs can be seen:

> 10.204.11.124 - - [26/Feb/2019:12:54:41 +0100] "GET /template.ks HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100
>   Safari/537.36" "-"

Down below is my kickstart config as well:

```
## Keep the following settings untouched
# Install OS instead of upgrade
install
# SELinux configuration
selinux --permissive
# Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
# System authorization information
auth --useshadow --passalgo=sha512
user --name=a18zagbi --plaintext --password=Syp9393
# Root password "Syp9393" (one line, no spaces)
rootpw --iscrypted $6$9+Nbh&q4j5$FW0HCHLVlEAto7DMNIlXnb9DDsh70AqnWvT4.FkSnDbbWXb/b3Evj/2lA2Qq.VBpc72v285gb8bWebc5hAW5k1
# Use text mode install
text
# The Setup Agent is not started the first time the system boots.
firstboot --disable
# Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
# System timezone
timezone --isUtc Europe/Stockholm
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
# Installation logging level
logging --level=info
# Use network installation
url --url="http://files.nsa.his.se/labfiles/it334g/MIRRORS/centos/centos-7-x86_64/"
## Fill in the correct settings for your installation to succeed
# Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --hostname=www.a18zagbi.it383g.nsa.his.se
# System keyboard
keyboard --vckeymap='sv-latin1'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8
# boot partition (/boot)
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size=512 --ondisk=sda --label=BOOT
# swap partition
part swap --size=2048 --ondisk=sda --label=SWAP
# root partition (/)
part / --fstype=xfs --size=2048 --grow --ondisk=sda --label=ROOT
# sshd automatically at boot
services --enabled sshd
# packages to be installed
reboot --eject
%packages
@base
@core
wget
patch
tmux
nano
vim-enhanced
telnet
bind-utils
open-vm-tools
%end
%post
umount /dev/sda1
tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sda1
mount /dev/sda1 /boot
usermod -aG wheel a18zagbi
%end
#>> for you to fill in
```

I would be grateful for every suggestion and all help i can recieve. If there is any further information that needs to be complemented. Please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved!

Due to vmware remote console not supporting a swedish keymap.

In the following line:

> inst.ks=http;//10.204.11.10/ks.ks

We can see that there is a semicolon

> ;

instead of an double dot

> :

On vmware remote console. both of these looked the same. Changing it, made it all work.

Genuine and first world misstakes. Thank you for youre time reading this.